# Slickgrid: Is it possible to pass options to an editor?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

For example: LongTextEditor has fixed width and height:

```
$input = $("<TEXTAREA hidefocus rows=5 style='backround:white;width:250px;height:80px;border:0;outline:0'>")
      .appendTo($wrapper);
```

It would be nice to have it parameterized, something like this:

```
$input = $("<TEXTAREA hidefocus rows=5 style='backround:white;width:"+options.width+";height:"+options.height+";border:0;outline:0'>")
      .appendTo($wrapper);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve it as follows.

Pass options list to columns array

```
var columns = [
        { id: "Id", name: "NAME", field: "FIELD", options: YourList, editor: Slick.Editors.YourEditor,},
              ];
```

Then you can access it in your editor(Default file for editors `Slick.editors.js`)

```
 function YourEditor(args) {
     //Access columns list using "args.column.options"
 }
```